# Is it OK to route a signal trace under an STM32?

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, layout, swd, signal-routing

Is it okay to route an SWCLK signal (for programming the STM32 microcontroller) under the STM32?

I will use it only to program it whenever I need it; it is not something that is always active.

Please see the attached figure:

[image]

Look at the yellow trace under U1 (STM32G071RB) routing from P3:2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no problem with that. You can route underneath TQFP/TSOP/SOIC/DIP chips (and anything else that's isolated on the underside) as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely safe to route SWCLK signal beneath the IC package. As soon as you are maintaining the gap between two traces it's okay, in your case this is completely safe.

I have routed the same way in many different projects and haven't faced any issue yet.